# why is -4 a rational number

Tags: rational-numbers

I need  to know why -4 is a rational I am very confused. I am doing my homework and have been stuck on this question the whole time I thought that it would be a intger.

edit:thanks for the help

Comment: Is an apple a fruit?

Comment: Every integer is a rational number.

Comment: If this is an apple, how can it also be a fruit?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}=\{\frac{p}{q}|p\in\mathbb{Z}, q\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}$. Do you find such a notation for $-4$? Which?

Comment: $-4=\frac{-4}{1}$, ie is representable by $\frac{a}{b}$ where $b \ne 0$ and $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Comment: Although you have already received answers it is still in your best interest and the interest of the community to mention what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number is rational if it can be expressed as the ratio of two integers, which $-4$ can: $\frac{-4}{1}$. It is also an integer; the set of integers is a subset of the set of rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$-4 = \frac{-4}{1}$, that is to say, it can be represented as a ratio in the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $b \ne 0$ and $a$ and $b$ are integers. This is the definition of a rational number.

$-4$ is also an integer, and integers are a subset of rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The set of all integers are in the set of rationals. Just like how the set of all naturals are in set of integers.